# How Adobe Shadow Chrome Extension be able to catch dom changes without any relevant permissions in manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Adobe release new interesting product - Adobe Shadow. And in its core is a chrome extension which listen for connection of a remote devices (its also interesting how this is done, but i think its might utilize own http service to communicate such request), but whats more interesting is that it listen for DOM, JavaScript and CSS changes (using chrome inspector for developers) and communicate this changes to othere devices. Yet in manifest this extension is only declare it was aware of only tabs switch activity - how this is possible?

Comment: Why not take a look at the code yourself? It's the best way to learn and it's what we'd have to do without guessing. [Find out how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250163/how-do-directly-modify-a-google-chrome-extension-file-crx/4980410#4980410)

Comment: Have no urgent interest in this. Yet i think its might be interesting for community. Because its actually seems that there is some way to go around manifest permissions and access page content.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect about the Shadow Chrome Extension listening for DOM, JavaScript and CSS changes in the page.  When you click on the Remote Inspection button in the Chrome Extension, we open a window to a weinre server and inject the required weinre javascript into the page on the device.The weinre window looks like Chrome Dev Tools because they both use WebInspector, which is part of WebKit.

[Read More About This In The Shadow FAQ](http://forums.adobe.com/community/labs/shadow?view=documents)

[Read more about weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre)

The Shadow Chrome Extension doesn't listen to anything at the page level.  It gets the URL to send out to devices from the tabs permission.

Answer (score 1):

I've only had a quick look at the ("confidential" marked) code I recommend you take a look at the `skylab.js` file.

It appears they're primarily using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to make the calls to a service running on your machine at . I'm guessing this belongs to the Adobe Shadow fat client.

Perhaps because your call an already existing service that's running on the local machine Chrome does not require any additional permissions. I've searched the code and see no mention of optional permissions either.

This is very interesting as I imagine this could be a concern for security, but maybe only on machines which are already infected with  malicious code.