# How to track if somebody has modified my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Edit: to clarify - i just found out that it is really easy to modify existing extension: [How do I directly modify a Google Chrome Extension File? (.CRX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250163/how-do-directly-modify-a-google-chrome-extension-file-crx)

Know i wanted to know if i can track if someone has done this with my extension?

And if the automatic updates still work if someone uses such modified version of my extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always obfuscate/minify the code (using something like [Closure Tools](https://developers.google.com/closure/) or [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/), etc.) to prevent tampering. It wouldn't "track" modifications, it would just make modifications much more difficult.

Automatic updates for your extension would still work. A user wouldn't actually modify your extension in place, they would effectively be copying it into a local unpacked extension which runs the modified code. So your extension would still update as long as it's still enabled. If a user unpacks your extension into their own local copy and disables your extension however, they would not get updates to your extension.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reliable way to do that. Implementing any tracking method would itself expose the running tracker having the risk of being crippled itself altogether;

You could instead use NPAPI to build your extension and distribute it in binary format.