# How to generate a chrome extension from directory automatically by a program?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, and I wonder that is there any way to compress a developing directory to `.crx` file that can be installed in chrome by program like using Python or NodeJS?

I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250163/how-do-directly-modify-a-google-chrome-extension-file-crx) saying that you can change the `.crx` to `.zip`, and after decompressing you can see the extension's code.

So, I tried it in reverse. I compressed my developing chrome extension directory to `.zip` file-format manually and change `.zip` to `.crx`, then I tried to install it in chrome, but it didn't work. Obviously, using program to compress a directory to `.zip` the rename it to `.crx` doesn't work.

How to generate a chrome extension from directory automatically by a program? I am using python and NodeJS.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome has support for packaging an extension from commandline, use this:

```
chrome.exe --pack-extension=C:\myext --pack-extension-key=C:\myext.pem
```

for more info: [chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html)

Comment: It seems not work for me..but I've found this post:http://grack.com/blog/2009/11/09/packing-chrome-extensions-in-python/, it solves this problem using python.