# Where are installed Google Chrome extensions stored locally?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have installed Google Chrome's extension [Chrome Office Viewer (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-office-viewer-beta/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj) for open Excel, Word and Power Point documents in browser. And now I need to install this extension to others computers in local network.
The problem is that the computers is not connected to the Internet.

How can I extricate (get) installed Google Chrome's extension for installing to others computers (offline)?

Comment: I wrote a small python script to download the crx file 

https://gist.github.com/arulrajnet/2424bc1ffc40324f3786

you can use that also.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Chrome extensions are stored in your filesystem, under the *Extensions* folder, inside [Chrome's user data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

**Windows XP:** `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\<Extension ID>`

**Windows 10/8/7/Vista:** `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\<Extension ID>`

**macOS:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/<Extension ID>`

**Linux:** `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/<Extension ID>`

**Chrome OS:** `/home/chronos/Extensions/<Extension ID>`

You can copy the extension folder and drop it on a USB or in a network drive.

### To install

- Open Chrome and go to `chrome://extensions`.
- Make sure *Developer Mode* is checked.
- Click *Load Unpacked Extension...*.
- Find your copied directory and click *Open*.

The extension should install locally.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu the path is `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions`.  [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1300686)

Comment: In my case Mac Path: ``/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/<Extension ID>``  Extension ID can be found at ``chrome://extensions`` (with ``Developer Mode`` enabled)

Comment: On OSX Yosemite use ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/<Extension ID>

Comment: I'm running kali `uname` output `Linux kali 5.10.0-kali7-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1kali1 (2021-04-12) i686 GNU/Linux` and the proper directory is `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions`. there is no directory named `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions`

Answer (score 5):

1. Rename the file extension .crx to .zip , like ( example.crx to example.zip )
2. Extract the zip file using Winrar or similar software
3. and Enjoy :)

Comment: The idea here is not to extract the extension for modification. Extract was used in the sense that it can be collected for use elsewhere. Your answer fits in somewhat with [How do I directly modify a Google Chrome Extension File? (.CRX)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2250163/914686), but not here.

Comment: You even don't need to do this. Just turn .crx into .zip right in browser using the tool I've created – http://crxextractor.com

Answer (score 4):

To download the crx  without store access, use this url.
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D~~~~%26uc

//replace the ~~~~ characters with the id of extension :

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimate-user-agent-switc/**ljfpjnehmoiabkefmnjegmpdddgcdnpo**?hl=fr

To install an extension from a crx file, open Extension page and drag and drop the crx inside.

Comment: I tried do https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dgbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj%26uc it does not work.

Comment: can you try download it? with this link [https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dgbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj%26uc](https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dgbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj%26uc)

Comment: They have move the repository for extension when I try to use it. I will try to find a new url.

Comment: thanks for answer, but when I drag and drop .crx file in Extension page show me this error **"CRX_HEADER_INVALID"**

Answer (score 0):

**in window you should first enable hidden file** and then go to this directory :
Windows 10/8/7/Vista: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\Extensions\<Extension ID>`

in above directory you will see extentions by id

Comment: i have extension in development but it is not present in this folder

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, now its in path:  `~/.config/google-chrome/Profile\ 1/Extensions/` due to introduction of Profiles