# Manually add extension to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have downloaded an extension  for chrome, but When I try to add it to chrome I get an error: "This can only be added from the Chrome Web Store".
What should I do?

Espicially I want to add "Chrome Remote Desktop" from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en). I downloaded it from [This Site](http://chrome-extension-downloader.com).
I tried both answers but I still get the same error.

Comment: http://www.superuser.com that's what you should do.

Comment: You should add it directly from the Chrome Web Store page instead of trying to download it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

follow these steps

```
1) Unzip the .crx (it is ZIP format) into a new directory
2) Remove or rename _metadata/ subdirectory, if present
3) In Chrome browser url type:chrome://extensions/
4) Check on Developer mode.
5) Select "Load unpacked extension..." and select the directory from 1)
```

Comment: This is also not working.

Comment: try to unzip the .crx file using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250163/how-do-i-directly-modify-a-google-chrome-extension-file-crx    then try the above steps.

Comment: I unziped it and followed the above steps. It works. Thank you.

Comment: Works here, being some systems/apps dont allow zip operations on unknown file types.. simply rename the .crx to .zip first

Comment: thx bro it was very helpful

Comment: However, you have to keep the extension folder in the same path, it is sadly not integrated in the chrome profile...